# Change carrier settings in iPhone post iOS7, possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cellular-carriers, sim

I recently moved to a new country, and got a new SIM for use over there. The sim came with an old no-name android phone, that works fine (can use data, call, text, all).

When I insert the same sim in my iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1, it can receive calls & texts, but not make calls, send texts or use the data connection. I assume this is because it still has my old carriers settings. Pre iOS 7 there was a setting to change carrier settings, but it seems to be gone? Is it possible to go around this, with or without jailbreaking?

If it's of interest, I changed from ePlus in Germany to Softbank Prepaid in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to http://www.unlockit.co.nz on your iPhone and follow the instructions. There are similar sites as well that do the same thing, and you don't even have to be jailbroken. There are some tweaks that enable the APN settings in the Cellular section of the Settings app, though, if that's what you really want.